# Como limitar o tamanho do heap em uma JVM 8?

Tags: java-8, jvm

Até a jvm 7 o parâmetro -Xmx limitava o tamanho do heap, mas hoje na jvm 8 isto não esta acontecendo.

Hoje uso o parâmetro -Xmx200m e minha aplicação chega a consumir 1.5GB no heap, utilizo muito objeto de curta duração então praticamente eles ficam no eden.

Já tentei vários parâmetros mas nenhum com sucesso. A questão que meu servidor esta derrubando algumas aplicações por falta de memória e eu gostaria de limitar o tamanho do heap delas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), você pode fazer isso usando o parametro `-XX:MaxHeapSize`.

Comment: Acho que você não leu a pergunta direito. E o link do metaspace foi para uma pergunta minha que tem relação com esta. 

Eu afirmo que utilizo objetos de curta duração e que todos ficam no Eden e mal passam para o Survivor 0 e 1. E que gostaria de saber se tem como limitar o tamanho do heap pois tenho limitação física de memória RAM na máquina que utilizo. http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Java_Heap_Diagram_12.jpg concorda que estamos falando de coisas diferentes? Estou falando da área verde e você da área marron da figura, só para pontuar minha permgen area é 50MB.

Comment: Eu entendi sua pergunta. Inclusive eu apontei que o Java 8 não trata mais esse tipo de coisa. Se sua aplicação está comendo muita memória então você precisa usar menos memória ou comprar um servidor melhor. Limita ro tamanho da heap só vai provocar erros na sua aplicação.

Comment: é para provocar erro sim mas não derrubar outras aplicações mais importantes. Bem, pelo que você me diz o parâmetro -Xmx não é mais válido, mas porque esta na documentação ainda? Java 8 é o grande consumidor de memória e o que podemos fazer é comprar outra máquina? Não há como limitar o tamanho da memória utilizada por ele e apontar à equipe de desenvolvimento? É isso?

Comment: Beleza cara, se você queria que o erro ocorresse deveria deixar claro na sua pergunta. O que consome memória não é o java é sua aplicação De qualquer forma, editei minha resposta..